# How to make two CSS elements that share class name different?

Tags: css, css-selectors, conditional-statements

Two elements have the same class name, in my case, "img"

Is it possible to style the elements differently that are children of two different classes, even if they have the same class name?

I want the img elements under class "slide-type-final" to be styled different to the img elements under "question-2"

```
.slide-type-final>img {
    max-height: 40em;
}

.question2>img {
    max-height: 40em;
    display: inline-table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`img` isn't a class name in this case, is it? Apart from the solution you already have in your question (?), ...:

1.) You can apply a second class to the parent(s), like `<div class="slide-type-final up"><img scr="...">`, whose `img` child  you would address as `slide-type-final.up>img { ... }`

2.) You can apply different classes to the `img` tags, like `<div class="slide-type-final"><img class="up" scr="...">`, which you would address as `slide-type-final>img.up { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

it would be helpful if you can provide html structure. and yes, css styles can be override based on parent element/class.

if styles in your code are not overriding, that means hierarchy is not correct.

'>' symbol means img tag (note not class as to catch img class you should have .img) should be direct child of element with class slide-type-final or class question2. if weight of classes are same, then whatever style come last will apply

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo-classes like nth-child(2n)/first-child/first-of-type/last-child

Or :not(:last-child) etc.